# How to listen the EditText when I focus on the window by using C/C# in Windows

Tags: c#, c, wpf, winapi

I made a virtual keyboard by WPF. I want to let it show up when I click/touch the EditText in any application in Windows. Such as Google Search [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTULc.jpg)]. Is there any solution? Is there anyway to listen the event of user to touch it by WinAPI using C#/C++?

[image]

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read stackoverflow.com/help/How-to-ask - what have you tried, what problems do you have.

Comment: You talk about touch.  But you also mention clicking.  Which is it?  Both?  How can you identify that the focus is on a control that accepts text input?  In general in Win32 there is no way to do that. Developers can implement a thing that looks like an edit control in any way possible.

Comment: Hi David, I want to try both click and touch. Thanks for your answer. It seems like I need to find another way.